# Is it possible to change the colour of a chart's border using Google App Script? [Google Sheets]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

From my own research it appears this is not possible - but I wanted to ask this forum before I accept that I can't adjust a charts border using app script.

I have no example script to give. The chart is pre-existing, and is not generated by my script. I simply want to set the charts border to white.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this through the UI going to *Edit Chart-> Customize-> Chart border color*, however, it seems that this cannot be achieved in Apps Script at it seems there might be a bug regarding this behaviour that I took the liberty to report. You can take a look at it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150189790).

Comment: Thanks heaps for the response and the additional info.